# How do I use fsarchiver to make a backup of only a particular BTRFS sub volume?

Tags: btrfs, chroot, fsarchiver

Does anyone know to use `fsarchiver` to make a backup of only a single BTRFS subvolume ?

Will [this](https://forums.debian.net/viewtopic.php?p=658053#p658053) mechanism work ?

```
1. Mounted the snapshot in /mnt:
mount -t btrfs -o subvolid="id" /dev/sda2 /mnt

2. chroot snapshot:
mount --bind /dev /mnt/dev
mount --bind /proc /mnt/proc
mount --bind /sys /mnt/sys
mount --bind /media/fsbackup /mnt/media/fsbackup
chroot /mnt

3. Fsarchiver backup from btrfs snapshot
fsarchiver savefs -Av -s 2400 -z 2 /media/fsbackup/backup.fsa /dev/sda2 \
```

Comment: It won't help. You should just mount the subvol on e.g. `/mnt` and use `savedir` (with `/mnt` as the directory to save) instead.

Comment: Alternatively, consider https://btrfs.wiki.kernel.org/index.php/Manpage/btrfs-send